# Create a real-time plot in a Fortran cycle by calling Matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have a cycle in Fortran, and I would like to call a Matlab script that at each iteration simply plots the 2 variables I am computing, always in the same figure, in a way that I can see how my solution evolves in time (basically a video)

```
do i=1,n
   Y(1:m) = blabla 
   X(1:M) = blabla
   write X and Y on file 
   RUN a matlab script which reads file and plots X and Y
enddo
```

If there is a way to bypass writing on the file and I can pass the variables as an argument even better cause it will be more efficient (I doubt it is possible). Basically, I want the results plotted in real-time so I can catch if the solution is unstable without having to wait until the end of the simulation.

Comment: Why MATLAB? Seems like a good way to complicate things. I would suggest opening a pipe to Gnuplot instead.

Comment: I think a standard solution would be to just write out the data (maybe only every other time step) and then use matlab/python/gnuplot/etc. to create animated graphics. this is not realtime as you requested but what is your issue with this standard solution? hard drive capacity? real time?

Comment: Real time. I want it real time. I dont wanna have to wait until the end if the solution is unstable after 2 time steps. I wanna see step by step the solution in real time

Comment: I clarified "real time"

Comment: what do you think about writing out data points to a file whenever your program generates a new data point. then have a script that creates a figure from the file and have it look for changes of the file. if there are any then create a new plot. I could write a bash script for that if you are using linux.

Comment: If you are willing to use python, then there's https://github.com/jacobwilliams/pyplot-fortran

Answer (score 2):

**Just something that might be useful (feel free to edit and build upon this)*

An animated plot may help with the video like plotting that occurs within the same figure. I tried to push as much as I could into a function. No clue how to achieve passing variables to the MATLAB script from Fortran (will look into it).

---

But if you were willing to calculate all the points first and then pass them to MATLAB to be animated this might help (a caveat is that this **wouldn't** have that real-time timing when the data is calculated and immediately passed for plotting).

[image: Animated Plot]

```
clf;
Animated_Plot = animatedline;

for x = 0: +1: 100    
    y = 0.5*x;
    Add_Data_Points(x,y,Animated_Plot);
end

function [] = Add_Data_Points(x,y,Animated_Plot)
    hold on
    addpoints(Animated_Plot, x, y);
    drawnow
    axis([0 100 0 100]);
    xlabel("x"); ylabel("y");
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**